# float to string using roundtrip

Tags: c#, tostring, number-formatting, roundtrip

I'm trying to convert a float to it's string representation without the result appearing in scientific notation.

I first tried :

```
ToString("0." + new string('#', 7))
```

but this doesn't seem to work for large values. For example :

```
float largeNumber = 12345678f;
string str = largeNumber.ToString("0." + new string('#', 7));
```

results in `"12345680"`

I then tried `ToString("R")`

this works for the large number above, but if the numbers get too large, it displays them in scientific notation. For example `5000000000f` results in `"5E+09"`. And small numbers like `0.0005` result in `0.0004999999966`

I've also tried mixing the 2, but I still get scientific notation in some cases.

My test program is pasted below. I appreciate that there will be precision issues, but I'm wondering if I can do any better than what I have?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Write(0.123456789f);
        Write(0.12345678f);
        Write(0.1234567f);
        Write(0.123456f);
        Write(0.12345f);
        Write(0.1234f);
        Write(0.123f);
        Write(0.12f);
        Write(0.1f);
        Write(1);
        Write(12);
        Write(123);
        Write(1234);
        Write(12345);
        Write(123456);
        Write(1234567);
        Write(12345678);
        Write(123456789);

        Console.WriteLine();

        float f = 5000000000f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i)
        {
            Write(f);
            f /= 10;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        f = 5000000000f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i)
        {
            Write(f < 1 ? f + 1 : f);
            f /= 10;
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Write(float f)
    {
        //string str = f.ToString("0." + new string('#', 7));
        //string str = f.ToString("R");
        string str = Math.Abs(f) < 1 ? f.ToString("0." + new string('#', 7)) : f.ToString("R");

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `float` only supports 7 digits of precision. There's no way to represent `12345678f` *precisely* in a float, so it gets converted to the nearest representable float value, which is `12345680f`.  It's not the *size* of the number, but the number of digits of precision that is the key issue.

Also, `0.0005` cannot be represented *exactly* in a binary floating-point number; the closest 8-bit binary floating point number to `0.0005` is `0.0004999999966`

`decimal` supports much greater precision, and can represented base-10 numbers precisely using the standard `N` format specifier.

Comment: Why does float f2 = 12345678f; string str = f2.ToString("R"); work then?

Comment: @pastillman In some cases there can be (smart) rounding. So f2 is still what f2 is, however it prints something a bit rounded.

Comment: From my understanding of roundtrip, ToString("R") shouldn't be doing any rounding

Comment: Try `123456789f`  - `"R"` will not give you the same number back

Comment: Sure, but '12345678f' does, so doesn't that mean it IS representable?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
largeNumber.ToString("r")
```

You can find the list of available formats here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The documentation discourage the R format. "For both Double and Single values, it also offers relatively poor performance"

Answer (score 0):

The `0` in the format string is not for zeroes, it represents "digit if non-zero and zero if zero", while '#' represents "digit if non-zero or nothing if zero".

You can use the format `f.ToString("0." + new string('#', 7))` for numbers over zero

I just tested it in PowerShell and it works fine for me, although it's probably using doubles or decimals:

```
PS C:\> $test = "{0:0.0######}"
PS C:\> $test -f 0.5
0,5
PS C:\> $test -f 0.4443423
0,4443423
PS C:\> $test -f 123.4443423
123,4443423
PS C:\> $test -f 45425123.4443423
45425123,4443423
```

Definitely, the problem seems to be `float` precision:

```
PS C:\> $test -f [float]45425123.4443423
45425120,0
```